# Enable cloudflare on multiple subdomains when using VPS with nginx?

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

There is a VPS machine with nginx’om configured on which 10 sites are spinning structure

```
tester.example.com
api-one.tester.example.com
api-two.tester.example.com
api-3.tester.example.com
api-4.tester.example.com
api-5.tester.example.com
api-6.tester.example.com
```

central site spinning on a separate hosting

in nginx, I configured the default site tester.example.com to use ssl from the cloudflare service

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name tester.example.com www.tester.example.com;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {

  # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
  ssl        on;
  ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/private.pem;
  ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare.crt;
  ssl_verify_client on;

  server_name tester.example.com www.tester.example.com;

  root /var/server/site/;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


  location / {
       # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8880;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }
}
```

without https - using regular ip: Port, opening passes through all services

how can I make api-one.tester.example.com config, etc. so that they also open via ssl?

I tried to change the port in the subdomain config (8443 which supports cloudflare), but does not give the desired result

```
.....
listen 8443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:8443 ssl http2;
ssl        on;
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally have to setup subdomains separately in Cloudflare DNS settings, unless you use *.wildcard, but I don't think they support that any more.

If you want Cloudflare to route all subdomains on https/ssl, there is an option on Cloudflare dashboard > Crypto > **Always use HTTPS**. In this case, your domains will redirect to https if they were accessed by plain http. This of course requires that your server is setup to support SSL for the domain (regardless of Cloudflare) OR that you are using "Flexible" under Crypto > SSL settings, which allows Cloudflare to serve your website to the client on https, although the data from your server to Cloudflare is served without SSL.